# Lambda boto3 function to verify if a cloud trail is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I need help with creating a lambda function to verify certain aws services is enabled or created. I need to create a script that would verify maice, cloudtrail, cofig is all configured/enabled. I started with cloudtrail but it's erroring out. I kinda need help.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client= boto3.client('cloudtrail')
    response = client.get_trail_status(Name='Test')
        
    print (response)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you edit your post and add the actual error you are seeing

Comment: Believe that you can call the Macie [list_members](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/macie2.html#Macie2.Client.list_members) method to see if it's enabled - it will throw InvalidInputException if not.

Comment: For CloudTrail, ensure that the [cloudtrail-enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail-enabled.html) managed rule is configured in AWS Config.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given so far, I believe that the issue is that you are not properly providing the '**Name**':

As per the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.get_trail_status), you need to provide the ARN of the trail, not just the trail name:

> Request Parameters
>
> For information about the parameters that are common to all actions,
> see Common Parameters.
>
> The request accepts the following data in JSON format.
>
> Name
>
> ```
> Specifies the name or the CloudTrail ARN of the trail for which you are requesting status. To get the status of a shadow trail (a
> ```
>
> replication of the trail in another region), you must specify its ARN.
> The following is the format of a trail ARN.
>
> ```
> arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-2:123456789012:trail/MyTrail
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: Yes
> ```